# .NET 5.0 - Stop immediately a running thread in WPF application

Tags: wpf, multithreading, .net-5, c#-9.0

I'm developing a WPF application for real-time data gathering from a remote client. Data acquisition is managed by a different thread (different from the one used to run the main application). When the users press the connection button, the data acquisition thread is launched and, simmetrically, when the disconnection button is pressed the thread should stop. Data reading stops only when the user decides it.
I use the following code:

```
private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   connectionThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myThreadStartFunc));
   connectionThread.Start();
}

private void myThreadStartFunc()
{
   TcpConnect();
   ReadData();
}

private void TcpConnect()
{
   mySocket = new Socket(...);
   mySocket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
}

private void ReadData()
{
   while(mySocket.Connected)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(300);
      mySocket.Receive(data, ...);
   }
}

private void DisconnectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   StopThread(connectionThread);
}

private void StopThread(Thread thread)
{

}
```

What should be the body of the `StopThread` method? Currently I'm using `thread.Interrupt()` in a try and catch structure in thte StopThread method. It generates an exception in the while loop of the data reading method, at line `Thread.Sleep(300)`: *System.Threading.ThreadInterrupted
Exception: Thread was interrupted from a waiting state.*

I would like to use the `thread.Abort()` method, but it is obsolete (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/thread-abort-obsolete). Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just close the Socket - assuming that ReadData() will terminate like DataReading(). It is unclear how the two methods are related.

Comment: Sorry DataReading() doesn't exist. Using `mySocket.Close()` in the `StopThread()`, I receive the _System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access to a disposed object_; at line `mySocket.Receive(data, ...)`.

Comment: Call Disconnect first and close it after the thread has terminated, or put the read loop in a try/catch block.

Comment: I would like to stop the thread first and after, close the socket. Sorry, I closed the socket not in the `StopThread`, but directly in the `DisconnectButton_Click` and then that exception was generated.

Comment: Sure, stop the read thread by calling Disconnect. `while(mySocket.Connected)` will terminate then.

Comment: @eljamba using `Thread.Abort` was *always* a bad idea, even in 2002. Instead of nuking the thread, and possibly leaving the application and its data in an inconsistent state,  tell the thread to stop. Before 2010 the common way was to use a synchronization primitive like an AutoResetEvent. Since 2010, it's using a CancellationTokenSource and passing a CancellationToken to the thread. You thread should check the CancellationToken to see if cancellation was requested, and exit when that happens

Comment: @eljamba if you used Thread.Abort you could *easily* end up with device ports locked by your application and no way to release them except restarting the application.